# Remove images from dhtmlxTree View

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I want to remove images from the Tree view shown in dhtmlxTree. I know that if we don't give any image file, there won't be any image shown. But, still the place for the image is left blank. I want to reclaim the place of the image. Can we do that in dhtmlxTree ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tree.enableTreeImages(false);
```

see this link for more options http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxtree:api_toc_categories